# PrimeFaces timeline

Tags: jsf, primefaces, timeline, primefaces-extensions

I'm using primeface timeline .first my timeline shows just loading then its displaying after I include code

```
<form prepenId="false" >
<p:timeline value="#{bean.value} />
</form>
```

.but my issue is the timeline shows just focus date in starting...and i cannot scroll or move content of timeline.the timeline is displaying just same content which s starting of my timeline (starting with focus date).but  cannot move ...to left n right...cannot view others . ruler appears but its not moving the content of timeline.

Comment: how about `h:form` instead of `form` ? also , try setting `showNavigation=true` and take a look at the showcase http://fractalsoft.net/primeext-showcase-mojarra/sections/timeline/basicUsage.jsf

Answer (score 1):

It's available zooming and navigate on timeline component default on primefaces extension. Be sure that you use newest version of "primefaces-extension" component instead of old "primefaces" timeline component. Primefaces transferred development of timeline to primefaces extension. Send your all of your bean and facelts code please.

But there is an other way to set the options of original timeline plugin which framework use.

Set widgetVar attribute of timeline component:

```
<pe:timeline id="timeline" value="#{bean.events}"  
                     eventStyle="box"  
                     widgetVar="timelineWidget">
```

Then put or run this javascript on your facelet page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
timelineWidget.jq.timeline(timelineWidget.cfg.dataSource,{"zoomable":"true"});
</script>
```

With this method, also you can set other properties which is javascript plugin support. Primefaces-Extension provide limited attributes of plugin.

Hope It'll help.

Comment: Also here the [link](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces-extensions/issues/detail?id=323) of issue for extend features of original timelime.js plugin on primefaces-extension